# How to define maximum results and parsing in Jquery AutoComplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

This is my script. Can you all tell me how and where to define maximum results code and  how to make it search from the beginning? It got minLength: 2. So now if I type 01 it
   shows results like  - 02301, 20165, 01674 .......... so on ..I wanted  the search results to be like 01001, 01002,01003 ...... so on on. like in Acc order.

I also  wonder how to  use xml file to extract the data.

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: [ 



    "(BWI)BALTMORE-WASHINGTON ARPT ,MARYLAND",  
"11-MILE CANYON RES ,COLORADO",  
"4 BEARS LODGE ,NORTH DAKOTA", 
"Aaron ,KENTUCKY",  
"AASU ,AMERICAN",  
"ABANAKA ,OHIO",  
"ABARR ,COLORADO",  
"ABBA ,GEORGIA",  



], minLength: 2,
});
  });
  </script>
```

I hope you can help me. Please I really need your help. 
Thanks

Comment: _"how to make it search from the beginning"_ - Do you mean you want to do a "starts with" search, or are you talking only about the ordering of the results?

Comment: I want it to start with the  values put by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the search results to be like 01001, 01002,01003 ...... you should use the 'startWith' function

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me where should I put " startWith " code? and Can you also tell me what can I do to make it show only 5 results maximum?

Comment: adding 'max:5' will show only 5 results maximum.                   And formatResult: function(row) { ... return 'row.value startWith somthing' }                                                         also formatItem:function(){} can make it search from the beginning ,of course it's due to you code within the function.